# What is the best way of loading different csv files into different SQL Server tables using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, ssdt-bi

Should I reuse the same Flat File Connection Manager or I should place individual Flat File Connection Manager for each files to be imported?

Description:

I have 30 CSV files with different structure and I need to import these files into the SQL Server database.

Currently I am using separate Flat File Connection Manager for each Flat File Source. Then pushing the data into the SQL Server database using OLEDB Destination.

Should I reuse the same Flat File Connection Manager?

Can you guide me - how to do this? Any links will be helpful.

Comment: Did either of these answers work for you?

Comment: is it right to assume your 30 CSV files map to 30 tables? if so separate connections would be the way to go, otherwise you might want to consider some pre-processing (depending on the file size) to get them into the same format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the structure differs between your files you should use separate connections.  This allows you to properly define the column names, sizes and data types for each file type.

Comment: sounds like the best option, I've done this in the past

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating 30 Flat File Connections just use one inside a Foreach Loop container passing in an Expression for the file name.

To solve the problem of your CSV files being in different formats, when you create the Flat File Connection select Ragged right instead of delimited, this will treat each row in file as one very wide column instead of multiple fields (make sure you make the column wide enough to handle your files).

You can then send the output of your Flat File Source into a Script Component, in to which you can put all the logic to handle your files. Use a Regex or a split to convert each row back into fields and then you have the full power of C# to process each row. A Script Component can also have multiple outputs so you can even use it like a Conditional Split.

This might seem like a bit more work (depends or what your files are like and how you are processing them), but then end result is less moving parts.

Comment: If I currently load a file using bulk insert, will it slow my process down significantly if I have to process each line in the C# script?  WouId I just use the script to create a consistent format and then still be able to bulk insert?  I need to handle multiple formats for a file now, which is indicated by a value in a column in one of the tables.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `MultiFaltFile` as Source connection Manager. Using this you can select multiple files at a time.

See the link below:

http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-import-multiple-files-in-ssis-using-multi-flat-file

Comment: I don't think this is an option for the OP, as the structure differs between files.